# Using PyQGIS Message Bar?

Tags: pyqgis

Having a bit of trouble with the basics of getting the (awesomely discreet) new user prompt/warning to properly display.  Here is the (troubled) code I am using:

```
self.iface
...
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Please select a Topographic Map for your simulation!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=2)
```

...and a bit more complete code for help in resolving this issue:

```
class GraphicGroundwater:
def __init__(self, iface):
    # Save reference to the QGIS interface
    self.iface = iface
    # initialize plugin directory
    self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    # initialize locale
    locale = QSettings().value("locale/userLocale")[0:2]
    localePath = os.path.join(self.plugin_dir, 'i18n', 'graphicgroundwater_{}.qm'.format(locale))
    # affirm window orientation
    if os.path.exists(localePath):
        self.translator = QTranslator()
        self.translator.load(localePath)
        if qVersion() > '4.3.3':
            QCoreApplication.installTranslator(self.translator)
# run add base
def run3(self, iface):
    if FindDirectory._destination is 0:
        iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Please select a central folder location to save your base layer(s)!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=2)
    elif FindDirectory._destination is not 0:
        if GetMaps._TOPOcrs is 0:
            iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Please select a Topographic Map for your simulation!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=2)
        elif GetMaps._TOPOcrs is not 0:
            crs = str(GetMaps._TOPOcrs)
            Base =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=' + GetMaps._TOPOcrs + '&field=LAYER:string(8)&field=BOTTOM:string(8)&field=TOP:string(8)&field=K:string(10)&field=R:string(10)&index=yes', "Base", "memory")
            QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([Base])
            pr = Base.dataProvider()
            BaseFeat = FindDirectory._destination+"/Base.shp"
            writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(BaseFeat, "CP1250", pr.fields(), QGis.WKBPolygon, pr.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile" )
            del writer
```

And here is the resultant conflict:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\GraphicGroundwater\graphicgroundwater.py", line 132, in run3
>       iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "Please select a central folder location for your simulation!", level=QgsMessageBar.CRITICAL, duration=2)
>   ***AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'messageBar'***

Any clues for a qgis_python_novi?

Comment: Iface is getting set to a bool some where. Can you post some more code for context?

Answer (score 0):

Goofed and overlooked an old aspect of code needing a change.
Trouble spot causing the error:

```
def run3(self, iface):
```

Solution:

```
def run3(self):
```

Works great now. Kudos to the QGIS developers for this seemingly less obstructing user/interface communication.